# Get all li elements text using Beautifulsoup and put it into variable separated by double quotes and commas

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I would like to get all text separated by double quotes and commas using python Beautifulsoup.

The sample has no class or ids. Could use the div with "Information:" for parent like this:

```
            try:
                test_var = soup.find(text='Information:').find_next('ul').find_next('li')
                for li in test_var.find_all:
                    test_var = print(li.text, end=","
            except:
                test_var = ''
```

Sample:

```
<body>
<div>Information:</div>
<ul>
<li>Text 1</li>
<li>Text 2</li>
<li>Text 3</li>
</ul>

</body>
```

The end result should be like this: "Text 1", "Text 2", "Text 3"

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

after `find_next()` you can select the the list using `.select('li')`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html ='''<body>
<div>Information:</div>
<ul>
<li>Text 1</li>
<li>Text 2</li>
<li>Text 3</li>
</ul>
</body>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
test_var = soup.find(text='Information:').find_next('ul').select('li')
listText = ",".join(f'"{li.text}"' for li in test_var) 
print(listText)
'''
for item in test_var:
    txt = f'"{item.text}"'
    print(txt) # "Text 1"
'''
```

Comment: This will print like this: [<li>Text 1</li>, <li>Text 2</li>, <li>Text 3</li>]

Comment: How to remove the [] and <li></li> elements ?

Comment: @tuuni updated the answer, you use `.join()`

Comment: There is still ul and li elements and also line breaks inside

Comment: I would like to get this into a variable in one line

Comment: This also works for me. https://imgur.com/a/sasazT2 where are <ul><li> tags and line breaks? I can't find them.

Comment: Maybe because you are using html.parser and i need to use lxml

Comment: I have tried to use `lxml` instead. It also worked.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/T02JD0t

Answer (score 0):

use `join` to concatenate strings in the `list`

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
ul = soup.find(text='Information:').find_next('ul')
", ".join('\"{}\"'.format(li.text) for li in ul.find_all('li'))
```

output:

> `"Text 1", "Text 2", "Text 3"`

Comment: This will print out html with <ul><li> tags

Comment: It will also have line breaks

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/TJd5pJd where are <ul><li> tags and line breaks?